# Parsing Value Showing Error in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
 SBJsonParser *parser= [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.krsconnect.no/community/api.html?method=bareListEventsByCategory&appid=620&category-selected=350&counties-selected=Vest-Agder,Aust-Agder"]];
NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
//NSDictionary *object = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];

  NSArray *results = [parser objectWithString:json_string error:nil];
NSMutableArray *data = [NSMutableArray array]
self.data = data;

// check that what we've parsed is NSArray
 if (results && [results isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
    for (NSDictionary *sectionDict in results) {
    if ([sectionDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        NSString *sectionTitle = [[sectionDict objectForKey:@"date"] description];
        NSArray *events = [sectionDict objectForKey:@"events"];
        if (date && events && [events isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSMutableArray *rows = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[events count]];

            for (NSDictionary *eventDict in events) {
                if ([eventDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
                    [rows addObject:@"testRow"];
                }
            }

            [data addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: sectionTitle, @"section", rows, @"rows", nil]];
        }

       }
    }
}
```

Now when i use this data in display on table view it show testRow on all cell but i want location on cell text and municipality in detailtext which come from JSON so how to do this

Answer (score 1):

change 
    [rows addObject:@"testRow"];
to
    [rows addObject:[eventDict objectForKey:@"location"]];

I'd suggest that you create a Event class with necessary attributes, such as location, municipality. Then you can do:

```
Event *event = [[Event alloc] init];
event.location = [eventDict objectForKey:@"location"];
event.municipality = [eventDict objectForKey:@"municipality"]]
[rows addObject:event];
[event release];
```

Then you can use the rows in your controller.

Comment: i am doing like this but it shows nill value in all and gives exception Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSCFArray objectAtIndex:]: index (76931520) beyond bounds (7)'